# WCF suppress returning __type in JSON response

Tags: json, wcf

Sorry this is a little long, but all the information is needed I beleive:

- .NET 4.5 with built in JSON.NET
- I have the following behaviours defined:

Viz:

```
<behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebBehavior">
            <webHttp helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetBinding="" httpGetBindingConfiguration="" />
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

for my service:

```
  [ServiceContract]
    public interface IWebServiceSrms
    {
        //-- Countries --------------------------------------------------------
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "/Countries")]
        [return: MessageParameter(Name = "Countries")]
        List<Country> Countries();

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "/Countries/{aId}")]
        [return: MessageParameter(Name = "Country")]
        Country Country(string aId);
        //-- /Countries -------------------------------------------------------
    }
```

I have implemented an IErrorHandler and then the following **ErrorResponse** to return JSON responses to clients:

```
[DataContract(IsReference = false)]
public class ErrorResponse
{
    public ErrorResponse(ErrorTypes aErrorType, ErrorNumber aErrorNumber, string aMessage)
    {
        ApiErrorBase = new ApiErrorBase {ErrorNumber = aErrorNumber, ErrorType = aErrorType, Message = aMessage};
    }
    public ErrorResponse(IApiErrorBase aApiErrorBase)
    {
        ApiErrorBase = aApiErrorBase as ApiErrorBase;
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "ApiError")]
    public ApiErrorBase ApiErrorBase { get; set; }
```

and the **IApiErrorBase** is defined as:

```
public interface IApiErrorBase
{
    ErrorNumber ErrorNumber { get; set; }
    ErrorTypes ErrorType { get; set; }
    string Message { get; set; }
}
```

and a concrete **ApiErrorNase** defined as:

```
[DataContract(IsReference = false)]
public class ApiErrorBase : IApiErrorBase
{
    [DataMember(Name = "ErrorType")]
    private string ErrType
    {
        get { return ErrorType.ToString(); }
        set { return; }
    }
    public ApiErrorBase()
    {
        ErrorNumber = ErrorNumber.ErrUnknown;
        ErrorType = ErrorTypes.UnknownError;
        Message = "";
    }
    [DataMember]
    public ErrorNumber ErrorNumber { get; set; }
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public ErrorTypes ErrorType { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

I then have a helper method to throw an exception which ultimately returns the error to the client:

```
public static class ErrorHelper
{
    public static void ReturnErrorToClient<T>(ErrorNumber aErrorNumber, ErrorTypes aErrorType, string aMessage, HttpStatusCode aHttpStatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest) where T : IApiErrorBase, new() 
    {
        T apiErrorBase = new T {ErrorNumber = aErrorNumber, ErrorType = aErrorType, Message = aMessage};

        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(apiErrorBase);

        throw new WebFaultException<ErrorResponse>(errorResponse, aHttpStatusCode);
    }
}
```

This all works well and as expected until I created the following **ApiErrorAnotherOne**  descendant class:

```
    [DataContract(IsReference = false)]
    [KnownType(typeof(ApiErrorAnotherOne))]
    public class ApiErrorAnotherOne : ApiErrorBase 
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Homer { get; set; }

        public ApiErrorAnotherOne()
        {
            Homer = "You don't make friends with salad.";
        }
    }
```

The first issue was I had to add **[KnownType(typeof(ApiErrorAnotherOne))]** as I received the following error:

```
aError = {"Type 'WebService_SRMS.Errors.ApiErrorSomeOtherOne' with data contract name 'ApiErrorSomeOtherOne:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebService_SRMS.Errors' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of kn...
```

However now my JSON response includes **__type** as below:

```
{
    "ApiError": {
        "__type": "ApiErrorDono:#WebService_SRMS.Errors",
        "ErrorNumber": 1,
        "ErrorType": "UnknownError",
        "Message": "",
        "Homer": "You don't make friends with salad."
    }
}
```

So my questions are:

1. Why is __type appearing in the response? (The rest of the response is as I want it)
2. How do I remove __type from the JSON response?

Comment: Anyone got any insights?

Comment: See the answer in
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730297/disable-type-hinting-in-wcf-json-services

Comment: I suggest you to use [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) instead. Apart from its better performance and more features support, you can use dynamic directive to parse json strings. I believe your issue would not appear if you use Json.Net.

Answer (score -1):

I think that is link you were looking for http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/05/03/wcf-extensibility-message-formatters.aspx

You need to write custom formatter and don't include handling for type in it.

Answer (score -1):

You need to instruct the service *what actually* it has to return. There are several ways:

- setting `ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json` in your `WebGet` attribute of your operation contracts
- specifying `defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"` in `webhttp` setting under behaviours in your web.config

Comment: I tried setting the ResponseFormat and I still get __Type in the results

Comment: same here. @ScottBeeson where you able to fix it?

Comment: Sorry, been too long and I don't remember :(