# How to include objects of different classes into a list in c# wcf and return them as json?

Tags: c#, json, wcf, serialization

Basically, we are now trying to figure out a way to generate a json using C# WCF like this.

```
[{Test1Class},{Test2Class}]
```

I've tried the following

```
[DataContract]
    public class TestBaseClass
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string baseproperty { get; set; }
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class Test1Class:TestBaseClass
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string test1property { get; set; }
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class Test2Class:TestBaseClass
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string test2property { get; set; }
    }
    //testing returns
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "history/testtest", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public List<TestBaseClass> ddd()
    {
        List<TestBaseClass> result = new List<TestBaseClass>();
        result.Add(new Test1Class());
        result.Add(new Test2Class());

        return result;
    }
```

And it doesn't work, nothing returned. No error no nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF's [data contract serializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) require that all types encountered in the object graph be declared beforehand.  Most commonly this happens through the type's data contract metadata which enumerates the types and names of properties to serialize.  When polymorphism is required, as it is in your class hierarchy, you need to either declare the expected subtypes with the [`KnownTypeAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Test1Class))]
[KnownType(typeof(Test2Class))]
public class TestBaseClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public string baseproperty { get; set; }
}
```

or by passing the list of known types to the [data contract serializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb908209(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<TestBaseClass>), new[] { typeof(Test1Class), typeof(Test2Class) });
```

Having done this, WCF's `DataContractJsonSerializer` will generate JSON for your list with [type hints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) indicating the actual types serialized:

```
[
  {
    "__type": "Test1Class:#Question33569121",
    "baseproperty": null,
    "test1property": null
  },
  {
    "__type": "Test2Class:#Question33569121",
    "baseproperty": null,
    "test2property": null
  }
]
```

Comment: Great! If there is a way to hide __type or type hint, it will be perfect. Is there?

Comment: @shawhu - not sure, but I found [Disable Type Hinting in WCF JSON Services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730297) and [WCF suppress returning __type in JSON response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768169)